# Jquery Datatables, change rowcallback after initialisation

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to get my hands on existing datatable's fnRowCallback setting but everything I try seems to fail.

What have I tried:

1:

```
var dt = $('#table').dataTable({
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "fnRowCallback" : function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)    {
             console.warn("working");
             }
        );
```

2:

```
var dt = $('#table').dataTable({"bRetrieve": true});

dt.fnSettings().fnRowCallback = function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        console.warn("working");
    }
```

No luck, but if I change

```
var dt = $('#table').dataTable({"bRetrieve": true});
dt.fnSettings().sAjaxSource = "invalid url";
```

I get an error so that one seems to work. Also if I do fnRowCallback in the original datatable initialisation it works, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted my old answer since I really didn't understand your post (it was late!)

It seems like you either have to use unofficial API, or destroy the old table and re-init it.

Unofficial API way (might not work in future version), tested; working in dataTable 1.9.2

```
$("#table").dataTable().fnSettings().aoDrawCallback.push( {
    "fn": function (oSettings) {
        if ( oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0 ) {
            return;
        }

        var nTrs = $('#table tbody tr');
        var iColspan = nTrs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
        var sLastGroup = "";
        for ( var i=0 ; i<nTrs.length ; i++ ) {

            var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
            data = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData;


            // Now you can access things like
            if (data.percentage > 80) {
                // And access the rows like this
                $(nTrs[i]).addClass("highlight-green");
            }

        }
    },
} );
```

Correct way: Save old settings, destroy, re-init

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable();

var oldoptions = oTable.fnSettings();

var newoptions = $.extend(oldoptions, {
    fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)    {
     console.warn("working");
    }
})

oTable.fnDestroy();

$('#table').dataTable(newoptions);
```

reference: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2737/addchange-callback-after-initialization-or-else-clone-settings-to-re-build-table/p1

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test this out once I get back to work in 2013 :) Happy holidays

Comment: You may also add `"bDestroy": true` option in the new init settings instead of calling `fnDestroy()`

Comment: @RoyLing Why use `push` instead of `=` when setting aoDrawCallback using the first way?

Comment: @YanYang if you read the doc of DataTables, aoDrawCallback is actually an array of objects with `fn` property, ie. callback, that said, it is like listeners for draw event.