# Rstudio Shiny reactive options list in renderDataTable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am trying to change the options of a `renderDataTable` call in Shiny to depend on the value of an input variable, in this case a checkbox.

The first checkbox successfully alters the content of the table, adding one more column if checked.
The second checkbox does not alter the options of the table. See code below, I am loading an updated version of datatables and other extensions, but that does not seem to have any effect here.
The third checkbox also does not alter the formatting of the entries in the table, which is what I ultimately would like to do.

Any ideas?

```
# server.R
library("ggplot2")
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
     bold = reactive ({
         bold = ''
         bold = paste0(bold,'function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {')
          bold = ifelse(input$checkbox3,paste0(bold),paste0(bold,'if (parseFloat(aData[0]) >= 0.1) { $("td:eq(0)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold"); }'))
          bold = paste0(bold,'}')
          return(bold)
     })
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
              diamonds[,1:ifelse(input$checkbox1,6,5)]
          }, options = list(fnRowCallback = I(bold()),aaSorting=list(list(2, ifelse(input$checkbox2,"asc","desc"))))
    )
  }
)


# ui.R
shinyUI({
      pageWithSidebar(
              h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
              tagList(
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='dataTables.colReorder.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='colvis.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
                        singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='ColVis.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css')))
                        , tags$head(
                                    tags$style(HTML("
                        .cvclear{
                         text-align:right}")
                                                       )
                                  )
                      ),
              tabPanel("foo",
                checkboxInput("checkbox1", "add one more column", FALSE),
                checkboxInput("checkbox2", "sort [desc] or [asc]", FALSE),
                checkboxInput("checkbox3", "no bold", FALSE),
                dataTableOutput("mytable")
                       )
            )
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is declared as:

```
"aaSorting": [[2,'asc']]
```

which in R is

```
options = list(aaSorting = list(list(2, 'asc')))
```

so you need to swap your `c` for a `list`. However the logic is wrong here.

> If sorting is enabled, then DataTables will perform a first pass sort on initialisation. You can define which column(s) the sort is performed upon, and the sorting direction, with this variable. The aaSorting array should contain an array for each column to be sorted initially containing the column's index and a direction string ('asc' or 'desc').

So this option will only work on the initialisation of the table. I dont think Shiny reinitialises the table once it has been formed so this wont work as a reactive only working the first time the table is initialised. Your more complex example may work however and it may just be the `list(list(...))` that is the problem.

Comment: I changed it to `list(list(...))` but yes, no difference in the actual issue, I'll change my question to do the more complex example.

Comment: It works fine notice it sorts at the beginning the reason it wasnt working for you was the incorrect specification. Can it operate as you want i.e. as a reactive? No because shiny doesnt recreate the data.table

Comment: Changing the question is slightly annoying. If you have a different question post it as seperate to this one.

Comment: Edited the question now. I don't mind creating a new one, but it will be very similar to this one, so this one would better be closed.

Comment: Thats ok it is useful to have this question related to `aaSorting` and why it wont react.

Comment: Again `fnRowCallBack` is defined when  the table is initialised. Shiny does not recreate the table so the new callback is not defined when the reactive fires. This question may help for a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912363/jquery-datatables-change-rowcallback-after-initialisation

Comment: Is there a shiny translation to the solution in javascript, or does it need injecting javascript?